# Eclipse outputting strange string at end of code

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently I began noticing that at the end of every code I run through Eclipse, it will end with an anomaly:

> [0x7FFABD5170E3] ANOMALY: use of REX.w is meaningless (default operand size is 64)

If seeing the entire code helps, here it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FracCalc {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int inputA(){
        System.out.print("Integer A: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        return x;
    }

    public static int inputB(){
        System.out.print("Integer B: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        return x;
    }

    public static double division(double n, double d){
        double a = (n / d);
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numerator = inputA();
        System.out.println("Divided by...");
        int denominator = inputB();

        double answer = division(numerator, denominator);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

If someone could help explain why this is happening that would be very appreciated.

Comment: IMO this has nothing to see with the code you posted. If you run a different application happens the same?

Comment: Most probably Eclipse dependent. Nothing to worry about, ignore it, or reinstall Eclipse.

Comment: If you Google for this there are numerous reports and it seems to be caused by TrendMicro - do you run that?